# Row value count

Tags: php, mysql, row

id | type
---|---------------
1  | online
2  | online
3  | online
4  | offline
5  | offline

I want count total type with "Online" value.
and echo the result in page.

---

Please, Can any one help me to echo the "online" Percentage ?

like:
Online is (3) = 75% of type

Comment: possible duplicate of [Echo row value as PERCENTAGE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415186/echo-row-value-as-percentage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code with your database credentials and table name.

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");
mysql_select_db("database", $link);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE type='online'", $link);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo "Online count: $num_rows\n";
```

Ref: http://www.php.net/mysql_num_rows

Comment: Please, Can you help me to echo the "online" Percentage ? like: Online is (3) = 75% of type

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table WHERE type='online'");
$total=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
echo "Total Online - ".$total["id"];
```

This will print total number of ids which are ONLINE.

Comment: `SUM(id)` will return 6 (1+2+3) instead of 3 (number of online ids). You should use `count(id)`.

Answer (score -1):

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.type=t2.type WHERE t1.type=t2.type AND t2.type='online' ORDER BY t1.type DESC,t2.type ASC UNION SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.type=t2.type WHERE t1.type!=t2.type ORDER BY t1.type ASC,t2.type DESC");
$dataa = mysql_numrows($data);
```